# The terminology for particular subsets of the power set of R

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

The set $X = \{\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x<a\}\mid a\in\Bbb R\}$ , which is a subset of the power set of R.

Is there a terminology for the set $X$?

My intent is to search the related literature about the set.

P.S. I am a layman of advanced mathematics, so my choice of the tags and the formulation could be inaccurate.

Edit: Let me clarify my set X.

A = {x∈R | x < 0}

B = {x∈R | x < -3}

C = {x∈R | x < the square root of 2}

D = {x∈R | x < e}

A, B, C and D are all the elements of the set X. Please correct me if I am still wrong on the formulations.

Edit2: Fixed the description of the set X.

Edit3: Fixed the fix.

Comment: The way you defined $X$ it follows that $X=\emptyset$, because for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\geq a$.

Comment: It would not be a subset of the powerset, it would be an element of the powerset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: $\{x \in \Bbb R\mid \forall a\in\Bbb R\;\; x<a\} = \emptyset$

This is because there is no real number which is strictly less than every real numbers, so the set is empty.

Did you mean $\{\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x<a\}\mid a\in \Bbb R\}$ ? This is $\{\Bbb R_{<a}\mid a\in \Bbb R\}$ and a subset of the powerset of the reals.

This is the set of all **lower open half-spaces** of the Reals; also known as the lower open rays.

$$\begin{align}
\{\{x \in \Bbb R\mid x<a\}\mid a\in \Bbb R\}
 & = \{\Bbb R_{<a}\mid a\in R\} 
\\[2ex] & = \{(-\infty; a)\mid a\in \Bbb R\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: How can I search the related literature about it?

Comment: @murali Look up "half-spaces" or "semi-infinite intervals".

Comment: Thanks much for your help :)